# Read csv file Anaconda | Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, csv, anaconda

I am trying to open a CSV file on Anaconda (Python 3) unsuccessfully.
I tried with a raw string, I included the whole path and also tried with the double backslashes but nothing worked. I still get the Errno 2 No such file or directory.

This is my code:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(r'C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\trainingset.csv',    newline=''), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
for row in reader:
    print(", ",join(row))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue when trying to open a csv file this way... I don't know the reason but instead, I use the pandas library that has a method named `read_csv()`

```
pandas.read_csv('myfile.csv')
```

It gets the content of your csv file as a dataframe object. This works with Python 3.5 using Anaconda3.